# Configuration of two WSO2AM nodes on All in One HA deployment config in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2-api-manager

I am tasked to create a WSO2 API Gateway (3.2.0) in Two Node cluster. Each node will be an all in one WSO2 API Manager on AWS EC2 VMS. Can any one who done the same or similar configuration shed light on the setup instructions. A step by step configuration will be really helpful.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the official documentation for this in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/#configuring-an-active-active-deployment

You basically need to configure deployment.toml file of both the nodes. Sample configurations can be found in https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-1/wso2am-pattern-1-am-conf.yaml

This is taken from the K8s configurations.

Comment: thank you pubci for your immediate response